# Where I can get a new set of pictures to customize a little bit my "own" xubuntu distro?

Tags: linux, xfce, xubuntu, distributions, icons

I'm just trying to graphically customize my "own" linux distro based on xubuntu,but focused on the virtualization. My idea is to configure it with all the files stored on the right places to allow the end user to virtualize any OS with qemu and kvm AND to passthru his nvidia gpu out of the box. In addition to this I want to prepare a special guest OS based on FreeBSD which will be virtualized on top of the custom ISO adding a lot of scripts useful for who wants to try the bhyve hypervisor. Having said that,actually I'm trying to customize the iso graphically,because I want that it looks a little bit different from xubuntu. I've looked inside the xubuntu squash file to understand where are saved all the png files that that make it look alike xubuntu and I've found them located on these folders :

> usr/share/backgrounds/
>
> usr/share/desktop-base/
>
> usr/share/help
>
> usr/share/icons
>
> usr/share/pixmaps
>
> usr/share/plymouth
>
> usr/share/ubiquity
>
> usr/share/ubiquity-slideshow
>
> usr/share/unity-greeter
>
> usr/share/xubuntu-docs
>
> var/lib/swcatalog/icons/ubuntu-jammy-universe/64x64

Let's say that I have 0 knowledge about how to draw a new set of pics,logo and icons for my distro. I think that the only way that I can do that is to find somewhere a pre-made set of graphic files,logo,icons which is copyright free. I'm not talking about this kind of icons themes :

https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/best-icon-themes-ubuntu

because this kind of icons is used when xubuntu is already installed. But the pictures that I want to change are mostly the ones you see while it is being installed. I've uploaded on my google drive all the pictures that I need to replace with another set of the same. I don't care so much to have something that's very personal. For me it's ok if the new set is funny and copyright free. Do you have some kind of idea to suggest ? I can't draw the xubuntu pictures one by one. I haven't neither the desire nor the competence to do that. Very thanks.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xj5LIGs7a2JGZHSSRrrI2_2EVCBS_UoZ/view?usp=sharing